# Eclipse - Problem Occurred using actual vs Project directory reference

Tags: eclipse, classpath, launching

Using Eclipse 2020 with 2 different Projects. Each Project has their own Workspace.

Workspace1/Project1 Run as expected.

Workspace2/Project2 generates the following error indicating an inability to find MyJarFile.jar:

[image]

All the Build values are the same, but when comparing the Dependencies between the working and failing environment I noticed the following.

The **working** environment shows reference to MyJarFile.jar as an actual path reference.

[image]

The **failing** environment shows reference to MyJarFile.jar as a reference via the Project Name.

[image]

The strange thing is when I first Add MyJarFile.jar it shows the actual path name, but after closing and reopening the Dependencies tab, it converts the \MyProject\ reference.

In both scenarios it has been confirmed the file exists.
Also, the addition of the File was done using the dialogbox so that also confirms it exists.

**Questions:**

1 - Is there a setting which dictates when the actual directory reference is shown and when the \Project\ reference is used?

2 - When the \Project\ reference is used, is there an extra step required so the associated file is actually found?

Comment: The .classpath file in the project sets the paths - what does that look like?

Comment: Should the .classpath be visible in the Package Explorer? I do not see one there.

Comment: Package/Project explorer normally hide file names beginning with `.`. This can be turned off in the view filters.